# how to choose which <p> to affect

Tags: css

I'm not sure how to affect only one <p when trying to customize the color or font. For example if I write

```css
p {
    Color: red;
    
}
```

It'll affect every <p in the code. What if I only want to affect one set of <p and not the rest. How do I specify to the code that I only want that one certain pair to be affected.

Comment: use class selector or id  selector like `p.myclass`

Comment: Give your p element an id and then you can set a rule for it using #<Paragraph ID>

Comment: `DO NOT give your element an ID` as mentioned above, that's just wrong when it's purely for styling purposes.

Comment: And make sure that your id is unique if you still want to do it that way.

Comment: you could simply add a id or class to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an ID or class in your HTML code.

```css
#test {
  color: red;
}
.example {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="test">Hello World</p>
<p class="example">Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The html tutorial I used never went over Id

Comment: just remember that IDs have to be unique, if possible, try to use classes instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
Small example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-keldysh-o5wek?file=/index.html